# Can I use match() with offset() in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using `match()` to locate a cell with a specific value in column A.

`=MATCH("Sales",A:A,0)`

This returns the row value `40` for example.

I want to then use this value with `OFFSET()` like so:

`=OFFSET(MATCH("Sales",A:A,0),1,1)`

So if my `match()` returned A40, `offset()` would then give me the value of B41. Unfortunately, this does not work. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: It would work with offset if you put =OFFSET(A1,MATCH("Sales",A:A,0),1,1) , but as @Scott Craner says, Index is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX instead:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("Sales",A:A,0)+1)
```

OFFSET is volatile and should only be used when no other option is available.